# Edit Multiple Files in GCP Storage Bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I have multiple JSON files in a GCS bucket that I need to export to BigQuery.

They are not newline-delimited I need to edit the files, and I'm looking to use the cloud shell to perform this on a large scale, since data dumps like this will happen often.

I was thinking it should be something along the lines of

`gsutil cat gs://triad_data/file_testing/Appointment.json | jq -c '.[]' > apptNDJSON.json`

but I have no clue how to pipe this for all items in my storage bucket. Is this the correct line of thought or is an operation like this not possible in GCP?

Comment: What the size of your files? Per file and the total? How many file do you have?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Every file is between 1-50 MB and there are 12 files at the moment, which is why I'd love to not have to deal with each file individually. The files will also be appended to at a later date, so the data size will grow.

Comment: Thanks, it was to be sure that fit the Cloud Shell capabilities. Anyway, you can't pipe into gs file. You store your file locally and then you perform another command to send the file to GCS

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere thank you for the response, so you're saying that if the files already exist in a storage bucket there is no real way to edit them in place?

Comment: Common mistake: Cloud Storage is not a file system. You can only Write, Delete and Read. No update, no move. You can activate the versioning for creating a new version, but you can't update the existing blob on GCS.

Comment: As @guillaumeblaquiere mentioned you cannot use GCS for that, with '[gsutil cat](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cat)', you concatenate objects to stdout, a similar command would be to use '[gsutil compose](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/compose)', but this joins the info of two files into a new one, which is not what he is looking for.
So yea as mentioned before the best way would be to download the files and then upload them again

Comment: Great, thank you both for clarifying this fact. Even though it's not quite the answer I hoped for, I appreciate you helping me understand GCS a bit better!

Comment: I also have the same problem, a json file in gcs, and want to use jq to parse some data into bigquery, but my json file has 20GB.

Have any one have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Storage is not a file system. You can only Write, Delete and Read. No update, no move. You can activate the versioning for creating a new version, but you can't update the existing blob on GCS directly.

On GCS and specifically with gsutil, the command ["gsutil cat"](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cat) is made to concatenate object content to stdout, in other words to show the content of a file on the console.

A command that is more similiar to what you're looking for would be ["gsutil compose"](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/compose) but this joins the content of File_A and File_B into a new File_C which is not what you are looking for.

You will need to code the app to download the file edit the content and then upload the file again or something similar